# User Update error no result for model auth/user laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

im getting error when updating user details ..please advice me . im using laravel version 5

Error

```
ModelNotFoundException in Builder.php line 125: No query results for model [App\User].
```

My controller file which i used auth/userController.php.

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $User =  User::findOrFail($id);
//    return $User->username;
        return view('auth.editUser')->withUser($User);
    }


    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  int $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update($id, Request $request)
    {
        $User = User::findOrFail($id);

        $this->validate($request, [
            'username' => 'required',
            'full_name' => 'required'
        ]);

        $input = $request->all();

        $User->fill($input)->save();

        Session::flash('flash_message', 'Task successfully added!');

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

and below is my routes

```
Route:: get('user-edit/{id}', 'Admin\UserController@edit');
Route:: post('user-edit/{id}', 'Admin\UserController@update');
```

below is my edit.blade.php file for the view

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ action('Admin\UserController@update') }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Full Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input  type="text" class="form-control" name="full_name" value="{{ $user->full_name }}">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Username</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input  type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="{{ $user->username }}">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input  type="password" class="form-control" name="password" value="{{ $user->password }}">
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                Register
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass a user id to your form like so:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{action('Admin\UserController@update', $user->id) }}">
```

You can also use form builder and do it like so:

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'action' => ['UserController@update', $user->id], 'class' => 'form-horizontal']) !!}
```

if the whole action part is confusing you can do it this other way:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{url('user-edit/'.$user->id) }}">
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming from your `findOrFail()` call. It is not finding a user with the id you're looking for.

This may be due to the order of the parameters in your `update` method. In the controller methods, the route parameters should be after the injected parameters. The [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers) states "If your controller method is also expecting input from a route parameter, simply list your route arguments after your other dependencies." Try changing your update method to:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id) {
    //
}
```

### Edit

Your POST route requires the user's id as a route parameter, but you have not supplied this when generating the URL for the `<form>`. The second parameter of the `action()` function takes an array of values to use as the route parameters. Your form statement should look like:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ action('Admin\UserController@update', ['id' => $user->id]) }}">
```

The documentation for the `action()` helper function can be found [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-action).

Comment: now im getting same error with url has changed to user-edit/%7Bid%7D

Comment: @fazfaz `%7B` and `%7D` are the curly braces, meaning the url you're going to is `user-edit/{id}`. This is not correct. Whatever code you have to replace {id} with the actual id is not working. It is not shown in your question. Update your question with your form opening.

Comment: @fazfaz You need to pass the user id into the `action` function. The second parameter should be an array of values to use for the route parameters. In this case, an array with just the user id.

Comment: : i didnt understand that .. can u kindly explain it :(

Comment: what he means is that you need to add parameters to your form. <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ action('Admin\UserController@update', ['id' => $user->id]) }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

Comment: action('Admin\UserController@update', ['id' => $user->id])

Comment: @fazfaz I have updated my answer with the explanation.